Why is my subdivision modifier adding geometry to my typology?
When I add a subdivision modifier to my object it adds extra geometry. Is it my typology or something else?
Here is the file: 



The Subdivision Surface modifier will try to round your shape with additional faces, for example with a L shape it will give that:

To avoid that you need additional edges:

On your object you can create this topology:

